# Get or Take: difference of meaning

Tags: meaning

Which of the following sentence is correct? If both are correct, what is difference between them?

I take a taxi/bus/train to work.

I get a taxi/bus/train to work.

Comment: what's your opinion? why? :)

Comment: The second one is not that common, it means someone provides car for you to travel to office by. On the other hand the first one implies that you hire or manages a car to go to office by.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, use "take" when you take some form of transportation to work (take a cab/bus/taxi/plane/skateboard/car), because a colloquial use of "get [something] to work" means you cause it to function properly. "I get a car to work" could be interpreted as "I had a non-working car and I made it function again." (E.g., "Hey, can you get that car running for me?" Or, "I'll be there as soon as I get my car to work." Or, "I'll answer your email as soon as I get my computer to work.")

Generally, if you use "get" to refer to your transportation, you have to get *on* it, and your destination is a separate part of the sentence: "I get on the bus." "I get on the train, to go to work." "I got on at Second Street, and I get off at Third Street." Further, it needs to be transportation you could plausibly *stand* on. (Though this may not be safe to do while the vehicle is in motion!) You get *in* your car to go to work. If you get *on* your car, then you are sitting on its roof or hood! But you can get on your skateboard, and you can get on your bike -- probably because you can put both feet on the ground while sitting on your bike, and you're not inside anything.

(Similarly, with nuance, you can get *on* a big plane, but would get *into* a small propeller-plane with no standing room.)

Answer (score 0):

"Take" emphasizes your *decision*, your *deliberate action*.  "I take a bus to work" means "I *choose* to go to work by means of a bus".

"Get" emphasizes that finding and boarding a bus is something you could have failed at.  "I got a bus at Sheppard Avenue." acknowledges that this action depended on chance, or depended on the actions of others.  "I went to Sheppard Avenue, and there was a bus there, so I got on it!  If there hadn't been a bus there, I wouldn't have been able to get on it."

Comment: For the sense of "get" you could also use "catch" (for the bus or train, but you'd "catch" a cab only if you hailed it on the street, not if you called to arrange it.)

Comment: And just to complicate things, you can say, "I don't feel like waiting for a bus: I'll get a cab", meaning that you'll arrange for a cab to come to your present location.